# Как сделать выезжающий блок?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Как сделать, чтобы изначально невидимый блок menu при нажатии на кнопку плавно выезжал справа на весь экран. Экран узкий мобильный.

```
<div class="container">
  <button>меню</button>
  <div class="menu" style="display:none; width:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну вы поняли смысл)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu_mobile').removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
});

$('.close-menu').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu_mobile').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.menu_mobile {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -700px;
  top: 0;
  padding: 40px;
  z-index: 50;
  background: #eee;
  animation-name: menuClose;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.menu_mobile.active {
  left: 0;
  animation-name: menuOpen;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.menu_mobile.active .close-menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 70px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes menuOpen {
  from {
    left: -700px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes menuClose {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: -700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>меню</button>
  <div class="menu_mobile hidden">
    <button class="close-menu">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем анимация, когда простого `transform:translateX();` достаточно? Или даже просто `left: 0 ; и   left:-100%;`

Comment: Зато впервые познакомился с @keyframes

Answer (score 2):

```js
// тут мы вешаем на кнопку МЕНЮ событие которое при клике на кнопку
// добавляет menu_mobile некий класс, в данном случае это active

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.menu_mobile').classList.add('active');
  document.querySelector('.close-menu').classList.add('close-menu-active');
})
// а тут мы вешаем на кнопку close-menu событие которое пр кликена кнопку
// удаляет menu_mobile  класс  active

document.querySelector('.close-menu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.menu_mobile').classList.remove('active');
  document.querySelector('.close-menu').classList.remove('close-menu-active')
})
```

```css
.menu_mobile {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: blue;
  transition: left 1s 1s;
}

.menu_mobile.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.close-menu {
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.close-menu-active {
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 1s 1s;
}
```

```html
<button>меню</button>
<div class="menu_mobile ">
  <button class="close-menu">X</button>
</div>
```

Вариант два, просто было нечего делать...

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const btnWrap = document.querySelector('.btn-wrap');
const menu = document.querySelector('menu');

btnWrap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  buttons.forEach(s => {
    s.classList.contains('active') ? s.classList.remove('active') : s.classList.add('active');
  })
  menu.classList.contains('open') ? menu.classList.remove('open') : menu.classList.add('open');
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2b2b2b;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.btn-wrap {
  position: relative;
  left: 25px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 5;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 1s;
}

.active {
  left: 0;
}

menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, .1);
  transform: translate(-150%, -50%);
  transition: transform 1s 1s, height 1s;
}

.open {
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform 1s, height 1s 1s;
}

li {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 3vmax;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
}

li span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

menu>li {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

menu.open>li {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s 1s;
}

menu>li span {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .5s;
}

menu.open>li span {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform .5s 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-wrap">
  <button class="open-menu active">Menu</button>
  <button class="close-menu ">Close</button>
</div>
<menu>
  <li class=menu><span>Menu_1</span></li>
  <li class=menu><span>Menu_1</span></li>
  <li class=menu><span>Menu_1</span></li>
  <li class=menu><span>Menu_1</span></li>
</menu>
```

Comment: Второй вариант просто супер , как раз думал над дизайном меню личного кабинета . А тут готовинький лучше бы я не придумал , спасибо.

Comment: @geepis, Всегда пожалуйста...